# How to create a multi-line node in Freemind?

Tags: mind-mapping, freemind

How can I create a multi-line node in Freemind? I don't need any formatting, just wrapped text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you're editing the node press alt+enter (or right click and select "Edit Long Node").